# C# comparing multiple type

Tags: c#, typeof

I have the following legacy code:

```
if (isOnMainWindow
    || (win.GetType() != typeof(winInputBox)
    && win.GetType() != typeof(winMessage)
    && win.GetType() != typeof(winMsgBox)
    && win.GetType() != typeof(winAbout))
    ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, win);
```

This looks horrible. Is there a way to compare multiple types of an objects as in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that can do just what you want, but why not use a simpler syntax:

```
if (!(win is winInputBox) && !(win is winMessage) && !(win is winMsgBox) && !(win is winAbout)) ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, win);
```

Alternatively, you can use a method to make your life easier:

```
public static IsNotOneOf(object obj, params Type[] types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And you can use it as this:

```
if (IsNotOneOf(win, typeof(winInputBox), typeof(winMessage), typeof(winMsgBox), typeof(winAbout)) ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, win);
```

Comment: Note that `win is winInputBox` is not exactly the same as `win.GetType() == typeof(winInputBox)`, the first will include descendant types, the second will not.

Comment: Yep, that is true, but I thought that was what Otto meant.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you can amend the classes, create a dummy interface like:

```
public interface IShouldNotClose
{
}
```

Define the interface as part of each of these windows and then your check becomes

```
if (isOnMainWindow
    || !(win is IShouldNotClose))
    ApplicationCommands.Close.Execute(null, win);
```

Comment: This answer would be good when they're starting to write it but, but modify legacy code to add interface, would cause a larger delta for testing, and will break the Open and close principle way more than just a standard refactor

Comment: But there is no change to the code of each of these windows types. Effectively all you're doing is decorating the class declaration.

Comment: you're decorating you class based on an implementation detail. If you need to reuse this code in another class, you need to decorate the class again

Comment: The re-use happens outside of the class, it only needs to be tagged for the common code to recognise it. As such you can re-use it in any Window class by simply appending ", IShouldNotClose" to the class header line like this:
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, IShouldNotClose

This will not require you to do this more than once per form.

Comment: This may force you to do it more than once, since the op stated this is legacy code, and were not aware of their architecture.

Comment: What architecture were you thinking of that changes the headers of existing form classes?

Comment: You're under the assumption that all the code that should not uses the MainWindow class

Comment: No, I gave that as an example. The same thing works with a Windows Forms app.

Comment: You're claiming that you will only have to change the code to inherit in a single place.  Which means that all windows will have a base class or a property which will implement the IShouldNotClose Interface.  But this is legacy code.  So Lets say there are 2 windows 1 that should close and one that shouldn't close.  You change their base class to implement IShouldNotClose.  Now they both don't close.  So either, you have to implement the IShouldNot close on each class individually,  or you have to be aware of the OPs architecture.

Comment: No, I'm claiming that, if you mark each window object that you don't want to close with the IShouldNotClose interface (and nothing else), then ONE library routine somewhere else in the code can detect that interface and NOT take an action based on it. Its the fact that it need NO code in the Windows classes, it's just used as a flag for the library routine, while at the same time being directly associated with the objects to which it applies, that makes it neat and elegant.

Comment: Then, that goes back to my first point, that you're affecting a larger delta than needed,  If you have 50 windows that shouldn't close then you have to change that in 50 places.  This is not more elegant at all.  You're now basing your objects on application specific behavior. e.g Maybe there using that class in a reusable library.  Now, you're exposing IShouldNotClose on a window.

Comment: In this case we have FOUR windows to which it applies. The Open/Closed principle says that Objects should be Open for extension, but Closed for modification. This is an extension that changes no code within the objects, nor their behaviour. In doing so it more closely follows OOP design principles in that the class it's self defines how it should behave, not a list in some random part of the code.

Comment: I don't think you understand OCP, because this is clearly a modification. Whether the window should close or not is not part of the class behavior, In some cases the window could need to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplifying it by using a List or HashSet

```
var typesToIgnore = new List<Type> { 
    typeof(winInputBox), 
    typeof(winMessage), 
    typeof(winMsgBox), 
    typeof(winAbout) 
};

if (isOnMainWindow || !typesToIgnore.Contains(win.GetType()))
{
}
```

Comment: pretty much the answer above

Comment: @kenny, the OP asked for a refactoring of his code, All answers should be pretty much the answer above.  The main benefit of this is you are duplicating the types on each function call, they're all contained in a single spot.